# Calculating geospatial statistics for large set of rasters and spatial objects in R

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile, r-raster

I am trying to calculate mean values for climatic variables for spatial objects in R. The challenge is that I'm trying to calculate these means for every level 2 administrative area in the world (www.gadm.org), and I need an efficient way of calculating the statistics. I have calculated these stats with no issues for smaller area definitions that span fewer climate zones/tiles, but the logistical issues have become a barrier when trying to scale this task up to the whole world.

I have tried by using gadm.org's level 2 boundary shapefile for the whole world, then importing and merging worldclim.org's complete set of bioclimatic rasters (at the highest available spatial resolution) and zones/tiles, but it appears to be too demanding on resources. Specifically, the operation of merging the complete set of raster zones/tiles into one global raster object never finishes. It seemed to be the most efficient approach as well as the most likely to minimize errors, to merge the raster zones for the whole world.

I am unsure how to approach the problem from here, as calculating these stats country-by-country seems extremely tedious and inefficient. Furthermore, there are a great number of shapes in the administrative boundary layer that overlap individual Worldclim zones/tiles, which would result in errors if relevant climate objects are missing from the calculations for the shapes that do not lie entirely within a single zone/tile.

I am wondering how I could come up with an efficient solution given the size of the operation.

After downloading the level 2 global administrative boundary data, I have tried the code below:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(foreign)

#SET WORKING DIRECTORY
setwd("C:/gadm28")

#IMPORT GLOBAL ADMINISTRATIVE BOUNDARIES (LEVEL 2) DATA FROM HARD DRIVE
gadm <- readOGR(dsn="C:/gadm28", layer="gadm28")

#IMPORT GLOBAL (ALL TILES) BIOCLIMACTIC DATA DIRECTLY FROM WORLDCLIM.ORG
climatezone00 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-180, lat=90)
climatezone01 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-150, lat=90)
climatezone02 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-120, lat=90)
climatezone03 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-90, lat=90)
climatezone04 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-60, lat=90)
climatezone05 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-30, lat=90)
climatezone06 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=0, lat=90)
climatezone07 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=30, lat=90)
climatezone08 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=60, lat=90)
climatezone09 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=90, lat=90)
climatezone010 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=120, lat=90)
climatezone011 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=150, lat=90)

climatezone10 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-180, lat=60)
climatezone11 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-150, lat=60)
climatezone12 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-120, lat=60)
climatezone13 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-90, lat=60)
climatezone14 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-60, lat=60)
climatezone15 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-30, lat=60)
climatezone16 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=0, lat=60)
climatezone17 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=30, lat=60)
climatezone18 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=60, lat=60)
climatezone19 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=90, lat=60)
climatezone110 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=120, lat=60)
climatezone111 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=150, lat=60)

climatezone20 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-180, lat=30)
climatezone21 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-150, lat=30)
climatezone22 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-120, lat=30)
climatezone23 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-90, lat=30)
climatezone24 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-60, lat=30)
climatezone25 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-30, lat=30)
climatezone26 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=0, lat=30)
climatezone27 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=30, lat=30)
climatezone28 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=60, lat=30)
climatezone29 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=90, lat=30)
climatezone210 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=120, lat=30)
climatezone211 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=150, lat=30)

climatezone30 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-180, lat=0)
climatezone31 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-150, lat=0)
climatezone32 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-120, lat=0)
climatezone33 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-90, lat=0)
climatezone34 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-60, lat=0)
climatezone35 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-30, lat=0)
climatezone36 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=0, lat=0)
climatezone37 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=30, lat=0)
climatezone38 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=60, lat=0)
climatezone39 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=90, lat=0)
climatezone310 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=120, lat=0)
climatezone311 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=150, lat=0)

climatezone40 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-180, lat=-30)
climatezone41 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-150, lat=-30)
climatezone42 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-120, lat=-30)
climatezone43 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-90, lat=-30)
climatezone44 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-60, lat=-30)
climatezone45 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=-30, lat=-30)
climatezone46 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=0, lat=-30)
climatezone47 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=30, lat=-30)
climatezone48 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=60, lat=-30)
climatezone49 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=90, lat=-30)
climatezone410 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=120, lat=-30)
climatezone411 <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=150, lat=-30)

#COMBINE ZONES TO CREATE ONE COMPLETE CLIMATE OBJECT
climatemosaic <- mosaic(climatezone01, climatezone02, climatezone03, climatezone04, climatezone05, climatezone06, climatezone07, climatezone08, climatezone09, climatezone010, climatezone011, climatezone10, climatezone11, climatezone12, climatezone13, climatezone14, climatezone15, climatezone16, climatezone17, climatezone18, climatezone19, climatezone110, climatezone111, climatezone20, climatezone21, climatezone22, climatezone23, climatezone24, climatezone25, climatezone26, climatezone27, climatezone28, climatezone29, climatezone210, climatezone211, climatezone30, climatezone31, climatezone32, climatezone33, climatezone34, climatezone35, climatezone36, climatezone37, climatezone38, climatezone39, climatezone310, climatezone311, climatezone40, climatezone41, climatezone42, climatezone43, climatezone44, climatezone45, climatezone46, climatezone47, climatezone48, climatezone49, climatezone410, climatezone411, fun=mean)

#EXTRACT MEAN VALUES FOR BOUNDARY POLYGONS & ATTACH TO SPDF (WEIGHT AND BUFFER OPTIONS NOT USED HERE)
gadmMEANS <- extract(climatemosaic, gadm, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, small=TRUE, layer=1, nl=19, sp=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would download and mosaic the data:

First, I would use a loop that downloads the data automatically and exports a .tif raster for each download.

After that, I would build a filelist with all the exported .tifs and create a virtual mosaic using the `gdalbuildvrt()` function. This will safe you some time and harddisk space.

Finally, you can use the `extract()` function to extract your values. note, that the extract function is **VERY** slow and takes forever for larger datasets like yours.

I would personally do this operation in an external software or other language like Python, ArcGIS or OTB ToolBox. Currently I am working a lot with the `otbcli_LSMSVectorization` function from the OTB Toolbox that enables you to extract zonal statistics (Mean/Var) based on a Zonal Input Raster and a Value Raster.

**Last word of advice:** Try to split you mosaic and your shp in smaller tiles/AOIs (as good as possible) and then run the `extract()` function, maybe combined with a `foreach` loop and `%dopar%`. This should decrease the processing time tremendously. For further information please look in the links below.

```
library(raster)
library(gdalUtils)

lon_vec <- rep(seq(-180,150,30),5)
lat_vec <- sort(rep(seq(90,-30,-30),12), decreasing=T)

#Download Worldclim Data and export as Tif
for(i in 1:length(lon_vec)) {
  ras <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=0.5, lon=lon_vec[i], lat=lat_vec[i])
  writeRaster(ras, filename=paste0("YourSubfolder/worldclim_lon_",lon_vec[i],"lat_",lat_vec[i],".tif"))
}

#Create list with all exported .tif iles
ras_lst <- list.files("YourSubfolder/",full.names=T, pattern=".tif$")

#Build virtual raster mosaic
gdalbuildvrt(ras_lst, "YourSubfolder/worldclimMosaic.vrt")

#Load virtual mosaic into R
climatemosaic <- stack("YourSubfolder/worldclimMosaic.vrt")

#Extract Mean Values
gadmMEANS <- extract(climatemosaic, gadm, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, small=TRUE, layer=1, nl=19, sp=TRUE)
```

- [Gdal BuildVRT](https://gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html)
- [otbcli_LSMSVectorization](https://web.archive.org/web/20160206055110/http://otbcb.readthedocs.org:80/en/latest/recipes/improc.html)
- [foreach %dopar% with extract](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130522/increasing-speed-of-crop-mask-extract-raster-by-many-polygons-in-r)